# how to get Difference of two variables

Tags: scripting, shell

I am new to shell scripting.

I want to know is there a way in which I can get a difference of two strings or values of two variables.

There are two variables:

```
value1 = "alok"  
value2 = "kumar alok"
```

so I want to get a result as

```
result = value1~value2
```

my expected result is

```
result="kumar"
```

is there any way I can do it?

can someone help me or give me some suggestions in the way it can be done...

Thanks

Alok.Kr.

Comment: What about "aaa bbb ccc ddd" vs. "aaa ccc"? How advanced do you want your difference to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a simple way with awk

```
value1="alok"
value2="kumar alok"
awk -v v1="$value1" -v v2="$value2" 'BEGIN{
  if(length(v2) >= length(v1)){
    sub(v1,"",v2)
    print v2
  }
}'

$ ./shell.sh
kumar
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you need  to have a look at
[this](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/Reference/string_operations_in_shell.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

As Lasse V.Karlsen says, it depends a lot on exactly what you want to get in different circumstances, but you could try the following:

```
result=`comm -3 <(for i in $value1; do echo $i; done | sort) \
                <(for i in $value2; do echo $i; done | sort)`
```

This will give you all words that are in either `value1` or `value2`, but not both. Change the `-3` to `-12` to get all words in `value2` that are not in `value1` (i.e. leaving out any words only in `value1`.)

For example:

```
value1="alok"
value2="kumar alok"
result=`comm -3 <(for i in $value1; do echo $i; done | sort) <(for i in $value2;  do echo $i; done | sort)`
echo $result
```

prints

```
kumar
```